# Javassist Clarification (Imports and InsertAt)

Tags: java, javassist

I would just like some clarification on a few things relating to Javassist.

**1.** Does the ClassPool.importPackage method physically add a line number to the class? For instance, if this was my code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Message!");// Line 3
    }
}
```

And I were to import the the "java.util.*;" package, would that print statement now be on line number 4?

**2.** Is there a way to add code at the method line number rather than the class line number? CtMethod.insertAt() requires a class line number.

**If anybody knew anything about this I would very much appreciate clarification, as the docs are very vague and nobody else seems to have found the need to ask this question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javassist does not change line numbers unless you tell it to. If you import a class in Javassist, this neither changes the class file but only serves as a hint to Javassist in what packages it should look for unqualified class names. In byte code, class names are always fully qualified.

Furthermore, Javassist does not support insertAt at a method level. You can however emulate this by iterating over a method's instructions and finding the first line number. Simply add an offset to this number.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid but can I have an example of iterating over a method's instructions and finding the first line number?

Comment: From the `CtMethod`, you can get hold of its `MethodInfo` instance. It even defines a convencience method `getLineNumber` which would serve your purpose: https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/bytecode/MethodInfo.html#getLineNumber-int- Note that it might return `-1` if the value is not defined where the `insertAt` approach will not work in the first place.